# Disable 'Hey Siri' programmatically in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, siri

Is it possible to disable the 'Hey Siri' function programmatically in an app? (iOS8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Siri is managed by the OS and is not able to be manipulated by sandboxed apps. Unfortunately, you cannot disable the "Hey Siri" functionality (or any Siri functionality) from within your app.

Think of it in the sense of scopes. You can only modify things that are within your app's scope, and Siri is out of scope.